# Adding a button to the format toolbar for custom styles

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to add a button to wrap certain characters with a span, in this menu

[image]

So far, what I came up with is to add this to my functions.php

```php
function enqueue_my_custom_inline_format_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-custom-inline-format-js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom-inline-format.js',
        [ 'wp-blocks', 'wp-rich-text', 'wp-block-editor', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n' ], // required dependencies for blocks

        '1.0.0',
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'enqueue_my_custom_inline_format_script' );
```

and this JS in `/assets/js/custom-inline-format.js`

```js
const { registerFormatType, toggleFormat } = wp.richText;
const { RichTextToolbarButton } = wp.blockEditor;

const type = 'finno/finno-underline';

registerFormatType( type, {
    title: 'Finno underline',
    tagName: 'span',
    className: 'finno-underline',
    edit: function( { isActive, value, onChange } ) {
        const onToggle = () => {
            onChange( toggleFormat( value, { type } ) );
        };

        return (
            <RichTextToolbarButton
                icon="editor-underline"
                title="Finno underline"
                onClick={ onToggle }
                isActive={ isActive }
            />
        );
    },
} );
```

But nothing seems to happen. As a matter of fact, I added a `console.log` to the JS file and the text never appeared on the console, which leads me to believe the code was never executed, even thought I double checked that the URI to the JS file is correct.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you added a `console.log` in the file, it should have appeared.
For a better debugging experience, you can wrap your code inside an IIFE which needs `wp` to be sure it is loaded:

```js
((wp) => {
  ... // your code
})(window.wp);
```

Also i'm not sure you can use JSX syntax here, your usage of `RichTextToolbarButton` should be instead:

```js
const { createElement } = wp.element;

...

return createElement(
  RichTextToolbarButton, 
  {
    icon: "editor-underline",
    title: "Finno underline",
    onClick: onToggle,
    isActive
  }
);
```